How to Color-Balance Field Photos for Accurate RGB Analysis in Photoshop?
I’m working in a lab studying how fruit color influences herbivory, and I need accurate RGB values from fruit photos to use as standardized data points. Each photo includes a color checker alongside the fruit specimen, but the photos were taken in the field under varying lighting conditions, causing slight differences in exposure and contrast. Photos are .jpgs
How can I color-balance these photos in Photoshop (or Lightroom, if necessary) to ensure the RGB values of the fruit are as scientifically accurate as possible? Is there a way to set RGB values of colors in the image to true the values on the card?  I understand that exposure and contrast can impact these values, so I’m looking for a way to standardize these variables across all the photos.
I know that it would have been ideal to make sure the orginal photos were shot in the same light/contrast environement, but I unfortunetly have no control over that. So looking to make do with what I can in post processing.
Once the colors are corrected, I plan to determine fruit color by selecting a representative area of the fruit using the rectangular marquee tool and applying a blur > average filter.
Could someone provide a detailed, step-by-step explanation for this process? I’m new to this and would really appreciate any guidance.

Are the photos only of the subject or did you include some type of photography color card in each photo? If the photos are only of the subject, I cannot imagine how you would scientifically get accurate color. I would think you would have to guess unless the lighting conditions are consistent or you have a control like a color card in each photo.

RGB values are not colors! They are device dependent values. So first thing to do is caracterize the camea and make a color profile for ir. Then you need to have a way to characterize the lighting conditions of each image, probably with a color card. And then you need to get rid of the jpeg compression error. Then you need to do error metrics for each of your images. Finally you need to write a chapter on how we can assume that the camera is a good measurement for anything other than a human vision (or even human vision)

Okay so i guess the right question is how many pictures do you have? I mean if you only have a few months of pictures may be better to redo them. But if you have 20 years of them then it might be better to come up with robust estimates for errors.

Post processing doesn't fix it. Reasons:

You do not know what the JPG maker software has done. Generally cameras process images heavily to generate pleasant looking color and exposure distributions. Colors change drastically differently in different areas of the image. Shooting RAWs would at least keep what the camera happened to catch. But letting the camera or some uncontrollable external process to generate JPGs wipes off the original spectral content (only three samples per a pixel).

Plants have color dyes which have steep wavelength dependent reflectance variations. If the spectrum of the light varies it's a math impossibility to recall what was the reflectance vs wavelength of the plant. Reference card in the image helps only if you can be sure that the light didn't have any wavelength peaks nor gaps. And, of course, there must not be any image processing out of your control.


Build at first a waterproof data gathering method. You must prove its consistency. Without scientifically waterproof data there's only counterfeits. I guess you do not want to become stamped forever. Do you?
If you use a camera instead of proper reflectance spectrometry equipment it's your job at first to show the exact math how the proper reflectance spectrometry results can be derived with the needed resolution from the photos. We cannot do it, because we cannot access your equipment nor see how they are used.
BTW. You may wonder why in the hell I talk about reflectance spectrometry when you only wanted plain accurate 3 numbers, namely R,G and B? Because R, G and B are not properties of the photographed plant. They are as much also properties of the used imaging system and the light conditions. Others cannot repeat the process with their systems and repeatability is the key feature in science.
Color measurement (if done properly) as CIELAB units L, a and b removes the effect imaging system out of the equation, but leaves still properties of human color perception to the equation, It could fortunately be repeated. The light would automatically be right if it's a proper Lab system measurement.
Reflectance vs. wavelength is a property of plants and as far as I understand, it's the one you actually should estimate to stay away from humbug.

This is not a detailed guide, but a list of topics to explore.
I. If you did not use a good CRI light some colors would not been captured at all. https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Color+Rendering+Index&t=h_&ia=web
Depending on what color chart you used the process is straightforward or... a pain.
II. A color chart like Xrite Color Checker or Datacolor are meant to generate an automated color profile of the photoshoot, this is a specific situation of lighting conditions and camera.
They should be used in conjunction to a RAW file, this is, the color chart will give the instructions on what the light should have done, and a raw file is important because the file can say "I did not interpreted the information in any form"
III. A JPG is a file with an interpretation embedded in it. The most drastic example is a Grayscale JPG or a Sepia look.
So. The bad news is that there is a big chance that the samples are really "contaminated"...
IV. But let us assume that you used a decent CRI, the color chart is a standardized one (Xwrite or Datacolor)
Then try to use raw software to generate a profile.
https://duckduckgo.com/?t=h_&q=how+to+use+color+checker+to+calibrate+your+photoshoot&ia=web
And by RAW software I mean Adobe Lightroom, DarkTable, RawTherapee, or ColrelAftershoot.
I can not guide you on the specifics or test if the software I mentioned works with JPG files.
